# Why does process.nextTick() trigger a TypeError in this "fake asynchronous function", but setTimeout() doesn't?

Tags: javascript, node.js

**Note: I ran this code on Node.js**

I was toying around with making a fake "non-blocking" function so I could understand how to write asynchronous functions for Node.js . While doing so, I came across this scenario that I didn't quite understand.

Below I have the code for a "fake" asynchronous function, that takes a callback function and a counter. The function will recursively call itself [counter] times, and will then execute the provided callback function. Every 10 iterations, it will release control back to the event queue.

**Original Script**

```
//fakeCounter helps us keep track of whether or not the operation is "complete"
//fn is the callback function that will be executed when the operation is complete
function asyncOp(fn, fakeCounter){
  //if fakeCounter is less than or equal to zero, that means the
  //operation is "complete" and you can call the callback now
  if(fakeCounter <= 0) return fn();

  console.log("another [" + fakeCounter + "] cycles to go");

  //every 10 or so iterations, release control
  if(fakeCounter % 10 === 0){
    process.nextTick(asyncOp(fn,--fakeCounter));
  }else{
    asyncOp(fn,--fakeCounter);
  }
}


asyncOp(function (){
  console.log("operation complete");
}, 10000);
```

As seen above, I release control by either using process.nextTick. However, when I execute the script, I am given this error:

**Original Result**

```
  another [10000] cycles to go
  another [9999] cycles to go
  another [9989] cycles to go
  ...
  another [3] cycles to go
  another [2] cycles to go
  another [1] cycles to go
  operation complete

  node.js:415
            callback();
            ^
  TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:499:11)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:902:3
```

This error and stack trace makes little to no sense to me, so I was left scratching my head for awhile.

However, when I modified the asyncOp function so that it releases control via setTimeout, no such error is raised:

**Revised Function**

```
function asyncOp(fn, fakeCounter){
  if(fakeCounter <= 0) return fn();

  console.log("another [" + fakeCounter + "] cycles to go");

  if(fakeCounter % 10 === 0){
    setTimeout(asyncOp(fn, --fakeCounter)); //<-- see here
  }else{
    asyncOp(fn,--fakeCounter);
  }
}
```

**Revised Results**

```
  ...
  another [3] cycles to go
  another [2] cycles to go
  another [1] cycles to go
  operation complete
```

And no errors were raised whatsoever.

... And so, my question is this: Why is it that using process.nextTick() raised the TypeError, but using setTimeout() didn't? And why exactly was the TypeError raised in the first place?

Edit:

In case anybody is reading this in the future, the correct answer, as @m02ph3u5 mentioned below, is to wrap the function call in an anonymous function:

```
if(fakeCounter % 10 === 0){
   process.nextTick(function(){asyncOp(fn, --fakeCounter)}). 
}else{
   asyncOp(fn,--fakeCounter);
}
```

However, in this specific example, it is better to use setImmediate instead of process.nextTick, as apparently recursive process.nextTick calls are going to be broken in the next version of node.js. Additionally, using process.nextTick() in this scenario will result in a RangeError. Therefore, the correct solution is to use the following:

```
if(fakeCounter % 10 === 0){
    setImmediate(function (){
       asyncOp(fn,--fakeCounter)
    });
}else{
    asyncOp(fn,--fakeCounter);
}
```

Thanks, @m02ph3u5 and @mscdex

Comment: `process.nextTick(asyncOp(fn,--fakeCounter));` Will execute `asyncOp()` and pass the result to `process.nextTick()`. Is this what you intended?

Comment: Ah, no, it wasn't what I intended. 

I intended for process.nextTick() to simply run asyncOp() with the provided arguments.

Comment: Thought so ;) pass an anonymous function instead. E. g. `nextTick(function(){asyncOp(fn, --fakeCounter)})`

Comment: Heya @m02ph3u5 - thanks for that. It was a silly mistake to make. However, when I **do** pass an anonymous function instead, I am instead greeted with the following errors:
**(node) warning: Recursive process.nextTick detected. This will break in the next version of node. Please use setImmediate for recursive deferral.**
**RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.**
After which I naturally replaced the process.nextTick() call with a setImmediate() call, which of course worked. However, why is it that setImmediate() does not trigger the RangeError? Should I open a new question for this? :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that `process.nextTick()` is expecting a function as the first argument and your `asyncOp()` is returning `undefined` (by default). `undefined` is not a function, so it throws a `TypeError`. `setTimeout()` currently does not immediately check the type of its first argument (this will change in node v6 however), so that is why it does not throw an error.

Comment: In case anybody is reading this in the future, the correct answer, as @m02ph3u5  mentioned above, is to wrap the function call in an anonymous function. **process.nextTick(function(){asyncOp(fn, --fakeCounter)})**. However, in this specific case, it is better to use setImmediate instead of process.nextTick, as apparently recursive process.nextTick calls are going to be broken in the next version of node.js

Comment: Actually in node v4+ you can do without the anonymous function: `process.nextTick(asyncOp, fn, --fakeCounter);`